# variable is undefined outside of subscribe() method Angular 2

Tags: angularjs-scope, angular2-services

I am working on angular 2 and getting undefined error for variable outside of subscribe() function.`employee` variable id `undefined` outside `subscribe()` function.Please help me.Thanks. Below is the code

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  employee;

  constructor(private _location:Location, private _empService:EmpService, private route:ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {
      //let params:any = this.route.snapshot.params;

      this.editEmployee(6); //I have tried to pass static value
      console.log(this.employee); //Here this is undefined  
  }
  backClicked() {
        this._location.back();
    }

   editEmployee(id) {
    this._empService.getEmployee(id).subscribe((employee)=> {
       this.employee = employee[0];
       console.log(employee[0]); //This have below output in console
       //{id: "6", emp_name: "Mohit", emp_email: "mohit@ommzi.com", emp_phone: "9800000", emp_status: "y"}
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using Observables, the `console.log(this.employee)` gets called before the employee is set. I would recommend in `editEmployee` that you return a Promise and use:

```
editEmployee(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this._empService.getEmployee(id).subscribe((employee)=> {
            this.employee = employee[0];
            console.log(employee[0]);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

this.editEmployee(6).then(()=> {
    console.log(this.employee);
}
```

Note that it's not the best and most beautiful solution, but if you want to keep your code in this style i would do it like this.

Comment: @PsychoPfanze : Thanks for your reply but this solution not working and there another error " Property 'then' does not exists on type void"

Comment: Sorry, i didn't post the whole code, i'll edit my answer to make it work for you :D

Comment: :Your answer is correct but unfortunatly my problem did not solve my issue.I am not able to use variable `employee` in `.html` file

Comment: You could do: `<span *ngIf="employee.id | async as employeeId">{{employeeId}}</span>`

Comment: `editEmployee(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this._empService.getEmployee(id).subscribe((employee)=> {
            this.employee = employee[0];
            console.log(employee[0]);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}`
In above function, I am assigning value of   `employee[0]` to   `this.employee`  so that I could use this in template file. but somehow its not accessable outside subscribe function . `employee` is undefined in template

Comment: A lot of things could be the issue, first: `public employee`, then i said you need to consider that the variable is now async so you have to use a pipe that it doesn't throw you an error on displaying it

Comment: can you tell me any function that can work in template inside {{ }} to see details of and array or object like console.log() or like we do print_r() in php ?

Comment: Use the pipe: json

Comment: `<span *ngIf="employee | async as $employee">{{employee | json}}</span>`